# How to display subsites of a page within grid columns of the grid layout on GetGridHtml() using Umbraco

Tags: asp.net, razor, model-view-controller, umbraco

I come across a issue on umbraco, suggest me how I can bind the subsites of a page within a grid layout of what I set as DataType. kindly do reply how to do it.

**note:

I don't want to use strongly-typed model to implement grid layout.**

```
@CurrentPage.GetGridHtml(Umbraco.AssignedContentItem,"postTiles",
"bootstrap3")
```

```
@CurrentPage.GetGridHtml(@Umbraco.RenderMacro("ArticlesList"),"postTiles","bootstrap3")
```

```
//ArticlesList

@inherits Umbraco.Web.Macros.PartialViewMacroPage

@{ var selection = CurrentPage.Children.Where("Visible").OrderBy("CreateDate desc"); }

<section class="container">
  <div class="row">
    @foreach (var item in selection)
    {
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <img src="@Umbraco.Media(item.ArticleFeaturedImage).Url" style="width: 200px; height: 120px;" />
            <h3>
                <a href="@item.Url">@item.Name</a>
            </h3>
            <p>
                &mdash; posted under <a href="#">@item.ArticleCategory</a> 
                &middot; @String.Format("{0:dddd, MMMM d, yyyy}", @item.CreateDate)
                &middot; by <a href="#">@item.WriterName.ToString().ToLower()</a>
            </p>
            <p>@Umbraco.Truncate(@item.ArticleDescription,100)</p>
        </div>
    }
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a custom rendering of some content in the Grid, you need to either:

- Use a Macro and have content editors pick the Macro in the Grid
- Create a [custom property editor](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/getting-started/backoffice/property-editors/built-in-property-editors/grid-layout/build-your-own-editor) and specific the rendering partial in the package.manifest
- Use a grid editor tool such as [LeBlender](https://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/leblender/) or [DocType Grid Editor](https://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/doc-type-grid-editor/) to create a custom editor and assign a custom partial for rendering

I'm not sure exactly if that's what you're looking for, but I think these may get you on the right track.

Comment: Thanks for reply @BeaverProj, but i required to display subsites in the grid layout. Please vist to the [link](https://wireframe.cc/FJq4Rw)

Comment: So you want multiple views or grids that you switch with jQuery or something?

Comment: Hi @BeaverProj, In each grid how to bind subsites.or how to set custom model to umbraco grid.

Comment: I'm unsure of what you mean by "subsites".  Like other sites in the Umbraco instance?  Have you tried looking at https://umbraco.tv/?  There is some information on the Grid and extending it there.